# Mobx state is lost when other React components access the store

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to learn how to use mobx with React Hooks.  But I don't understand why when one component loads the store data (using loadData()) I'm able to observe the updated values from the store but when an another component accesses the store data everything is reset in store data back to its default values.  What am I missing here?

My development platform is using Nodejs v12.16.1

My React dependencies are:

"mobx": "^5.15.4",
"mobx-react-lite": "^1.5.2",
"react": "^16.13.1",

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import { observable, action, decorate, flow } from "mobx";
import agent from '../api/agent'; 

import { history } from "../index";

class ApplicationStore {
    user = {
      profile: { id: null, firstName: null, lastName: null, email: null, phoneNumber: null }
    };
    loading = false;

    loadData = flow(function *() {
      this.loading = true;
      try {
        const payload = yield agent.User.get('defaultUser');
        this.user.profile.id = payload.user.profile.id;
        this.user.profile.firstName = payload.user.profile.firstName;
        this.user.profile.lastName = payload.user.profile.lastName;
        this.user.profile.email = payload.user.profile.email;
        this.user.profile.phoneNumber = payload.user.profile.phoneNumber;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        history.push('/systemDown');
      } finally {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
}

decorate(ApplicationStore, {
    user: observable,
    loading: observable,
    //loadData: action, //Defining as an action or not makes no difference
})

export default createContext(new ApplicationStore());  //NOTE: Creating context here.
```

```
const HomePage = observer(() => {
  const applicationStore = useContext(ApplicationStore);

  useEffect(() => {
    applicationStore.loadData();
  }, [applicationStore]);

  if (applicationStore.loading)
    return <LoadingComponent content="Loading data..." />;

  return (<DoSomething/>)
})
```

```
const DoSomething = observer(() => {
   const applicationStore = useContext(ApplicationStore);

   return (<div>
     // ERROR: applicationStore.user.profile is back to its default values.  Why???
   </div>)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed one thing. You forgot to decorate your components with `observer`.

```
//   --------------  IMPORTANT! ----------------
const DoSomething = observer(() => {...})
```

Here's a codesandbox to illustrate:

[image: Edit hardcore-hooks-4cdrp]

Comment: Actually, if you can directly check if the two `applicationStore` in two components are really referring to the same object, that’s even better. I suspect they’re not.

Comment: First off.  Thank you for responding.  I applied your suggestion to both components and 'same ref true' was returned for both.

Comment: Adding a timestamp to the store is works.  Same value for both components.   On a different note if I make the user.profile not observable it still looses it state while the timestamp value doesn't.

Comment: I was looking for clue if the ApplicationStore has been instantiated twice, if not then it’s really weird case. I don’t have no clue now. Would like to hear about the reason if you finally figured it out. Sorry couldn’t help you.

Comment: I thought defining loadData as an mobx action while it actually uses a mobx flow (generator function) might be the issue but it didn't make difference.  Bummer.

Comment: Also using the Object API mobx provides for setting the value of user in loadData makes no difference.  Bummer.

Comment: Just edit. You forgot to use `observer`, that's the root cause. Mobx need to notify react about change via `observer`. That's the whole point of importing "mobx-react-lite".

Comment: I do this this pretty much across the board in my project.   export default observer(ComponentName);

Comment: Well. Then I couldn't reproduce your error case. Check the codesandbox, everything you mentioned in description is there.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it by forking and by slightly modifying your sandbox.  Here is the sandbox:   https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hawking-ee3sl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You didn't really reproduce it. In applicationStoreContext.js `getUser()` is missing so it goes to error case "systemDown". The `user.profile` isn't reset but untouched.

Comment: You are correct.  I can't watch Black List and edit code at the same time.   My code sandbox has been updated.

Comment: I think I figured out what may be causing this problem.  My original app uses react-router-dom.  I believe this line from my App.js was causing the problem:  export default withRouter(observer(App));   I modified my app by removing any references to react-router-dom and now the Mobx store works fine.